# Plotting the spectrogram

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, matlab-figure

**Note:** This question is not about using the `spectrogram` function, it deals with data representation.

I have designed my own function to calculate spectrogram, because I need a custom solution for the type of input and parameters. It works just fine, but I got embarassingly stuck making the output plot.

The goal is to use e.g. `surf(X,Y,Z)` with the x,y-axes representing time and frequency as usual. I have a matrix `spectg` containing the spectrogram coefficients, vector `f` (frequency) and vector `t` (time).

Could you please share the code for plotting this. I am missing something very simple with `meshgrid` - probably having a bad day...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need `meshgrid` in your case. From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html),

> `surf(x,y,Z)` and `surf(x,y,Z,C)`, with two vector arguments replacing
>       the first two matrix arguments, must have `length(x) = n` and
>       `length(y) = m` where `[m,n] = size(Z)`.  In this case, the vertices
>       of the surface patches are the triples (x(j), y(i), Z(i,j)).
>       Note that `x` corresponds to the columns of `Z` and `y` corresponds to
>       the rows.

For example:

```
s = randi(10,4,5); %// example data
x = 10:10:50; %// example x, of length size(s,2);
y = 21:24; %// example y, of length size(s,1);
surf(x,y,s)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved the part of the problem I ask about... Meanwhile I realised a problem with definition of length of the time window, which causes the other part of my confusion... :-) Now everything works!